# AIDL file not exists or occured error after i m changing my package name

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this type of error

> Process command G:\Android_SDK\build-tools\27.0.3\aidl.exe
>
> finished with non- zero exit value 1

This is my AIDL file and interfaces with my package name

```
package com.xxx.api;
import com.xxx.api.iProfile;

interface IConfiguration {

    //Prefs
    void setPreferenceString(in String key, in String value);
    void setPreferenceBoolean(in String key, boolean value);
    void setPreferenceFloat(in String key, float value);

    String getPreferenceString(in String key);
    boolean getPreferenceBoolean(in String key);
    float getPreferenceFloat(in String key);

}
```

Comment: what is the **full error message** produced by `AIDL` compiler?

Comment: Process 'command 'G:\Android_SDK\build-tools\27.0.3\aidl.exe'' finished with non- zero exit value 1

Comment: No, I m getting this type of error after change package name :Process 'command 'G:\Android_SDK\build-tools\27.0.3\aidl.exe'' finished with non- zero exit value 1 and also project not compile

Comment: i m stored my aidl file in main/java

Comment: C:\Users\user\Desktop\New Package\ros\app\src\main\java\com\magic\api\IConfiguration.aidl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of package name change you can change a **FullPackage** name not change only **subpackage** name.

```
package com.newxxx.api;
import com.newxxx.api.iProfile;

interface IConfiguration {

    //Prefs
    void setPreferenceString(in String key, in String value);
    void setPreferenceBoolean(in String key, boolean value);
    void setPreferenceFloat(in String key, float value);

    String getPreferenceString(in String key);
    boolean getPreferenceBoolean(in String key);
    float getPreferenceFloat(in String key);

}
```